# ASP.NET SSO based on Windows credentials

Tags: asp.net, windows, authentication, iis-7, single-sign-on

I need to extend our existing ASP.NET Web Forms application so that local domain users don't have to login again. I need to find out who is the user and whether it is authenticated. If yes, he can access the application; otherwise, unauthorized access error occurs. Further, we need to check whether the user belongs to a specific user group (AD) and if yes, the request is redirected to the login screen (custom form authentication) and the user must login. If not, it is automatically logged in. And the last thing: other users (external) must be able to login (forms authentication).

First, I have a problem with getting windows credentials. I am using following statement in order to receive current user name:

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
```

However, if I understood it correct, it is the user IIS running on and not the user calling the application in browser. How can I get this user and how to query AD whether the user belongs to specific user groups? Is it possible at all?

Thanks,
Erno

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the http context user I believe:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hi Dinos,I tried this option as well but it doens't work. The problem is if I disable the anonymous authentication (only windows authentication is enabled in IIS) it works for local users but then external users have no access any more.